# TextInput add text on the right side react native

Tags: react-native

Hi guys this is my code

```
 <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row',paddingBottom:5, borderColor:'#ccc',borderBottomWidth:1}}>
     <TextInput
          placeholder = "Wallet"
          placeholderTextColor="#000"
      />
      <Text style={{alignSelf:'center'}}>
           {userData.wallet}
       </Text>
 </View>
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

[image]

when I try to `alignSelf:flex-end` it will go down due to `flex:'row'`

Help .

Comment: add `justify-content: space-between` to `View`

Comment: my god . hahahahaha

Comment: I make it as answer, and accept it to make me happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `justify-content: space-between` to `View`:

```
 <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row',paddingBottom:5, borderColor:'#ccc',borderBottomWidth:1,justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
     <TextInput
          placeholder = "Wallet"
          placeholderTextColor="#000"
      />
      <Text style={{alignSelf:'center'}}>
           {userData.wallet}
       </Text>
 </View>
```